# Convert epoch difference to number of days

Tags: perl, iso, epoch

I computed the difference of two ISO 8601 dates after coverting them to epoch.
How can I get the difference of them in number of days?
My code is

```
my $ResolvedDate = "2014-06-04T10:48:07.124Z";
my $currentDate = "2014-06-04T06:03:36-04:00"

my $resolved_epoch = &convert_time_epoch($ResolvedDate);
my $current_epoch = &convert_time_epoch($currentDate);

if (($resolvedDate - $currentDate) > $noOfDays) {
    print "Difference in greater than x\n";
    $built = 0;
    return ($built);
} else {
    print "Difference in smaller than x \n";
    $built = 1;
    return ($built);
}

sub convert_time_epoch {
    my $time_c = str2time(@_);
    my @time_l = localtime($time_c);
    my $epoch = strftime("%s", @time_l);

    return($epoch);
}
```

Here in addition to $built I also want to return exact number of days, Resolved date is greater than Current date.

Comment: First you need to define what variant of "day" you are using. For example, is it based on the local date (so two times could be 1 second apart, but if that is locally over midnight, then they are also 1 day apart)?

Comment: Also what about leap seconds? If you want to account for stuff like that, using DateTime instead of naive "seconds since the epoch" will save you *a lot* of work.

Comment: @DeVadder: Unix epoch deals with leap seconds by not incrementing, so that date maths should work just fine without accounting for them. Unless you want to unambiguously *identify* a leap second, which is not possible using the epoch.

Comment: @NeilSlater Hmm, right, but i stand with suggesting DateTime. ^^

Comment: Please don't use `&` to call subroutines. They aren't necessary and can have potentially confusing side-effects.

Answer (score 7):

"number of days" is awkward, because this is localtime and DST exists (or at least, may exist).

By simply dividing by 86400 you can easily obtain the number of 24-hour periods, which may be sufficient for your purposes.

If you want the true number of times that the `mday` field has changed, this may be slightly different from the value obtained by this simple division, however.

Answer (score 5):

If the dates are in epoch seconds, take the difference and divide it by the number of seconds in a day (which is 86400). Like so:

```
my $days_difference = int(($time1 - $time2) / 86400);
```

If you use [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) then

```
my $duration = $dt1->delta_days($dt2); #$dt1 and $dt2 are DateTime objects.
print $duration->days;
```

Comment: Re "the number of seconds in a day (which is 86400)", That's not true. Not all days have 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601 qw( );

my $ResolvedDate = "2014-06-04T10:48:07.124Z";
my $currentDate = "2014-06-04T06:03:36-04:00";

my $format = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->new();

my $dt_resolved = $format->parse_datetime($ResolvedDate);
my $dt_current  = $format->parse_datetime($currentDate);

my $dur = $dt_resolved->delta_days($dt_current);
my $days = $dur->in_units('days');
```